# Groovy and Spring Cloud Contract - Variable in the bodyAsValue

Tags: groovy, spring-cloud-contract

I would like to know how am I supposed to create in Groovy the Json payload with a random value.
For example

```
Contract.make {
    name"MyFirstContract"
    description "A description"

    request {
        method "POST"
        url "/api/team/createTeam"
        headers {
            contentType applicationJson()
            accept applicationJson()
            header"Authorization", execute('bearerOfAccessToken()')
        }
        body """ {
    "authenticatedUserCode":"papas",
    "input": {
        "name":"${execute('generateTeamUniqueName()')}",
        "teamDefinitionName":  "JUNIT TEST NAME",
        "context":"context AHO",
        "description":"team Description",
        "members":
           [
           {"role":"Junit Reviewer",
           "memberType":"USER",
           "reference":"papas"
           },
           {"role":"Junit Observer",
           "memberType":"USER",
           "reference":"papas"
           },
           {"role":"Junit Collaborator",
           "memberType":"USER",
           "reference":"papas"
           },
           {"role":"Junit Reviewer",
           "memberType":"USER",
           "reference":"papas"
           }
           ]     
    } } """
    }
```

The important part from the previous code is the following that fails during compilation.

> ```
>         "name":"${execute('generateTeamUniqueName()')}",
> ```

with the following error message:

```
 Execution default-generateTests of goal org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:3.0.2:gener
ateTests failed: expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 'E' with an int value of 69
```

Is it possible to call a method inside the body or I have to return the ALL the contents of the body through the same method???

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call it for the whole body, it won't work for part of it

Comment: Thank you Marcin, I thought that this is the case but I needed an extra confirmation

Comment: Marcin partially you loose the beauty/cleanness that the groovy test provides since we must escape the characters. We could possibly of course store the json body in files without the need to escape the characters, but this also adds a small extra layer of complexity. It would be very nice to have the feature to do the method call from the Groovy test. Thank you again!

Comment: Hi Marcin please have a look at this question since it is related with this one that you have blazingly fast answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67295698/spring-cloud-contract-body-and-execute-method-is-not-validating-the-response

thank you!