# Spring Cloud Contract, body and execute method is not validating the response

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, spring-cloud-contract

I have the following spring cloud contract:

```
package contracts.teams

import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    name"d Find team roles by filters"
    description "Find team roles by filters"

    request {
        method "POST"
        url "api/team/findTeamRolesByFilters"
        headers {
            contentType applicationJson()
            accept applicationJson()
            header"Authorization", execute('bearerOfAccessToken()')
        }
        body execute('getRequestForFindTeamRolesByFilters()')
    }

    response {
        status OK()
        headers {
            contentType applicationJson()
        }
        body execute('getResponseForFindTeamRolesByFilters()')
    }
}
```

I call the **getResponseForFindTeamRolesByFilters()** at the response in order to generate a dynamic response from the server. The reason could for example be an auto generated id that is coming from the DB.
The generated string from the **getResponseForFindTeamRolesByFilters()** is a valid JSON that unfortunately is ignored and returns always true when the test run.

I have noticed this when I replace the execute method with a static response like the following one:

```
"""
{
   "success": "false"
}
"""
```

In this case the response is being validated correctly and fails the test in case it does not match.
What I said is being confirmed by the test generated code as it can be seen here:

```
// then:
            assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(200);
            assertThat(response.header("Content-Type")).matches("application/json.*");

        // and:
            DocumentContext parsedJson = JsonPath.parse(response.getBody().asString());
            getResponseForFindTeamRolesByFilters();
```

As you can see there is no assertion. It simply calls the method that generates the json.

How am I supposed to make the test check the dynamic json response?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I call the getResponseForFindTeamRolesByFilters() at the response in order to generate a dynamic response from the server.

You should not do it. Contract tests should not access the database.

For the consumer you should do

```
request {
        method "POST"
        url "api/team/findTeamRolesByFilters"
        headers {
            contentType applicationJson()
            accept applicationJson()
            header"Authorization", execute('bearerOfAccessToken()')
        }
        body $(producer(execute('getRequestForFindTeamRolesByFilters()')), consumer("some value to be put on the consumer side"))
    }
```

For the producer

```
response {
    status OK()
    headers {
        contentType applicationJson()
    }
    body $(producer(execute('getResponseForFindTeamRolesByFilters()')), consumer("something in the stub"))
}
```